# Get phone number in flutter

Tags: android, ios, flutter, phone-number

i am a flutter developer and i am trying to get the mobile phone number of the current phone where the application is running

i try to do it with this plugin : sms_autofill: ^1.2.0
but that code only shows me a dialog to select a phone number, but for that to happen I have to have added my phone number to my google account and I want to get it from the sim, I need to obtain the phone number automatically because it is a requirement of a client, he does not want the user to be able to type it

```
final SmsAutoFill _autoFill = SmsAutoFill();
     final completePhoneNumber = await _autoFill.hint;
     print(completePhoneNumber);
```

Comment: It is not allowed in IOS so you can't get that because flutter is based on IOS and Android both equally... Instead you can ask the user to provide his mobile number and check it by sending sms on that phone number given by user and checking it by reading the sms

Comment: i am trying to do it in android, i have a client and he dont want to write the number

Comment: Did you find any solution ?

Answer (score 1):

You could try using [mobile_number](https://pub.flutter-io.cn/packages/mobile_number) package

Comment: I have not tried it yet so I don't know whether it works or no, but you could try and check

Comment: That package isn't working as of 2022